# PineScript strategy don't open orders/not responding when use strategy.exit() function

Tags: pine-script

So when I just use the strategy.entry() it works fine and it opens and closes trades as demanded. But once I put the exit conditions the script saves without any issue but doesn't open orders nor shows anything on chart.

Seems likes I've calculated the TP and SL levels correct because when I plot the values on chart with the plot() function it shows me the correct values. But seems like I'm doing something wrong on the strategy.exit() function

Here's part of the code:

```
//@version=4
//Buy and Sell Conditions
buy=c2>o2
sell=c2<o2

//Stoploss price (last top or bottom)
longstop = lowest(low,bars)
shortstop = highest(high,bars)


//Get stop values at the entry bar
entry_longstop = valuewhen(buy, longstop,0)
entry_shortstop = valuewhen(sell, shortstop,0)

//Calculate TP based on ratio of SL
longtake=strategy.position_avg_price + ((strategy.position_avg_price - entry_longstop) * rr)
shorttake= strategy.position_avg_price - ((entry_shortstop - strategy.position_avg_price) * rr)


 
strategy.entry("long", true, when=buy)
strategy.exit("TP", "long", limit=longtake, stop= entry_longstop)

strategy.entry("short", false, when=sell)
strategy.exit("TP", "short", limit=shorttake, stop=entry_shortstop)
```

Comment: I see no issues, I get the trades. Please share your complete code, and tell us the ticker id and timeframe you are testing this on.

Answer (score 0):

I entered a few extra details - different entry conditions and few other extras you'll want to change back - and eventually got shorts and longs working.

[Here's a screenshot of a chart with the strategy running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJDOT.png) Orders are opened on a simple EMA cross.

I compared my attempt with the code you posted and made some comments about the changes in the script. The only significant difference I could see was that I made the 'from_entry" argument of each strategy.exit function explicit. So for example, instead of `strategy.exit("TP", "short", limit=shorttake, stop=entry_shortstop)` we have `strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="short", limit=shorttake, stop=entry_shortstop)`

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © MattAnstey

//@version=4
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

///I added a simple ema cross and an RR ratio so the script would compile./// 

c2 = ema(close, 50)
o2 = ema(close, 100)
rr = 1.5

//Buy and Sell Conditions
///I added a condition to 'buy' and 'sell' which would ensure only one short or one long are open at a time.///

buy=crossover(c2,o2) and strategy.position_size == 0
sell=crossunder(c2,o2) and strategy.position_size == 0

//Stoploss price (last top or bottom)
longstop = lowest(low,20)
shortstop = highest(high,20)

//Get stop values at the entry bar
///I added a check for the entry price - the close price - at your buy and sell conditions, so I could plot the entry price later.  

entry_longstop = valuewhen(buy, longstop,0)
entry_shortstop = valuewhen(sell, shortstop,0)
entry_long = valuewhen(buy, close, 0) 
entry_short = valuewhen(sell, close, 0) 

//Calculate TP based on ratio of SL
///This formula is spot on. No changes.///

longtake=strategy.position_avg_price + ((strategy.position_avg_price - entry_longstop) * rr)
shorttake= strategy.position_avg_price - ((entry_shortstop - strategy.position_avg_price) * rr)

///Here I added conditions I could use to plot the entry, profit and stop levels when (and only when) the appropriate order was open.You probably have a better method. 

lorders = strategy.position_size > 0 
sorders = strategy.position_size < 0

///Now, the strategy.exit functions here are different. 
///I changed the id of each from "TP" to "exit", but that's incidental. 
///The only important difference I can see between the strategy.exit functions below and yours is that I added 'from_entry' and the name of the strategy.entry they apply to.
///Generally I type out all of the arguments in long form, e.g, strategy.exit(id="long", from_entry="long"...), etc. - maybe that was what helped? 

strategy.entry("long", true, when=buy)
strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="long", limit=longtake, stop=entry_longstop)

strategy.entry("short", false, when=sell)
strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="short", limit=shorttake, stop=entry_shortstop)

///Below are the plots I used to see what was going on. 

plot(lorders ? longtake: na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green)
plot(sorders ? shorttake: na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.green)
plot(lorders ? entry_longstop: na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red)
plot(sorders ? entry_shortstop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red)
plot(c2)
plot(o2)
plot(lorders ? entry_long : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.black)
plot(sorders ? entry_short: na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.black)
```